# what the best starter kit suited with SPA and api with sanctum tokens?

Tags: laravel, api, single-page-application, sanctum

I want to make a restful api using Laravel so I can use it with mobile application and SPA
I also want to use sanctum to authenticate tokens.
what is the most approperiate starter kit for my needs?
I tried Breeze but it seems doesn't suit with sanctum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel's starter kits provide only front-end assets with already implemented auth. Jetstream uses Sanctum already. But in your case, I would just use Fortify that doesn't have any frontend if you are making API for mobile app.

Comment: Does Fortify support sanctum, passport, jwt? do you think it's best to make register, login ... by my self without depending on starter kits?

Comment: Sanctum, password and jwt provides authorization methods which you can customize using your `auht.php` config. Fortify gives you routes for authorization. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#laravel-fortify-and-laravel-sanctum. As long as you do not need frontend, just use Fortify, yes.